# How to make session_write_close writes to the database in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I have a class that will allow me to regenerate the session_id on every request for security. However, I am trying to keep the previous session "the session before the newly generated one" active for only 15 seconds more to handle any ajax request..... Also, I am storing the session information into a database and not on the server's file system.

In order to do that I have to set the session values like so

```
$_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
$_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 15;
```

then after that I 
session_regenerate_id(false); 
and just before I start a new session with a new id I close the previous session

```
session_write_close();
```

The issue that I am having is that the OBSOLETE and the EXPIRES value are not being set into database. 
**Question:** How can I make session_write_close() function store that data into the database? If it should store the data in the database automatically, then what am I doing wrong that is not allow the system to store the data into the database.

From the PHP manual for `session_write_close()` it states that this function writes the session data and closes the session. But it does not mention anything about storing the data in the database as an option.

this is my function that regenerate a new session and write and close the previous session

```
public function regenerateSession(){

    // Set current session to expire in 15 seconds
    $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 15;

    //Create new session without destroying the old session. The old one should stay available for the next 15 seconds to allow any AJAX request to process
    session_regenerate_id(false);
    session_write_close();

    // Grab current session ID and close both sessions to allow other scripts to use them
    $newSession = session_id();

    // Set session ID to the new one, and start it back up again
    session_id($newSession);

    session_start();

    // Now we unset the obsolete and expiration values for the session we want to keep
    unset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']);
    unset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']);
}
```

this is how I initialize my script to store the session into a database

```
//set the session storage to point custom method
session_set_save_handler(
    array($this, "open"),
    array($this, "close"),
    array($this, "read"),
    array($this, "write"),
    array($this, "destroy"),
    array($this, "garbageCollector")
);
```

Comment: Why are you regenerating the session id on **every** request? What security purposes does that have Oo?

Comment: This makes your server just more vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: The session_id is generate on every request so that the session_id that is stored in the cookies won't be available after 1 request. So is it hard to guess it or even capture it. even if a hacker was able to capture the cookie value it most likely be useless since it would be obsolete. Why would it make it vulnerable to attacks if the garbage collector will remove it? it will need to be available for some seconds to allow the ajax request complete without issues.

Comment: Not more vulnerable to XSS attacks but ddos because your server needs a lot more resources to handle one request.

Comment: Check this thread out for more informations what **useful** steps you can take against session hijacking http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/session-hijacking-regenerate-session-id

Comment: @Xatenev, How so if I only generate the first one when the user logs in and then from there I regenerate on every request? so even if a some one try to overwhelm the server it is not going to happen because they will have to have a valid log in before they can get a session to begin with. Maybe I am missing something.